# Is it safe to Use TweakBox App on your IPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Have you used third-party app stores like Tweakbox on your iPhone? 
Using these kinds of types of apps is always a big security concern. If you have used [Tweakbox](https://www.techtree.com/content/news/13669/how-install-use-tweakbox-app-iphone.html), can please share your experience. And does it slow down your phone?

Comment: this is more of a opinion based question but to answer your query i think yeah it not a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its not a problem as apple screens most of the apps on appstore to prevent any security issues if you really wanna use it then there is no harm apparently.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: if it helped can you accept the answer please?

Comment: But surely the point of Tweakbox is that it allows you to install apps that *haven't been reviewed by Apple*, so by your logic, it is very *unsafe* to use.